# Error occuring on successful firebase authentication login

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I currently have this code to authenticate a user in firebase authentication:

```dart
class Auth implements BaseAuth {
  Future<String> signInWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      AuthResult user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      print(user.user.uid);
      return user.user.uid;
    } catch(e) {
      print('Error: $e');
      String code;
      switch(e.code) {
        case 'ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL':
          code = 'The email you specifed was not valid.';
          break;
        case 'ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND':
          code = 'The user could not be found.';
          break;
        case 'ERROR_USER_DISABLED':
          code = 'This user\'s account was disabled.';
          break;
        case 'ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD':
          code = 'The password you entered for this account is invalid';
          break;
        case 'ERROR_TOO_MANY_REQUESTS':
          code =
          'There have been too many requests sent from this device. Please try again later.';
          break;
        default:
          code = "There was an error with your request.";
          break;
      }
      throw(code);
    }

  }
```

When entering invalid credentials, the catch works fine and returns the error message to the place that is calling it. However,when I enter valid credentials, it throws this error:

```
W/BiChannelGoogleApi( 7405): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzak@8e5055f
E/JavaBinder( 7405): *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
E/JavaBinder( 7405): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/util/ArrayMap;
E/JavaBinder( 7405):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzam.zzc(Unknown Source:22)
E/JavaBinder( 7405):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzam.zzde(Unknown Source:17)
E/JavaBinder( 7405):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzam.zzdd(Unknown Source:8)
E/JavaBinder( 7405):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzan.zzdf(Unknown Source:1)
E/JavaBinder( 7405):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzm.isAnonymous(Unknown Source:47)
E/JavaBinder( 7405):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzat.zzi(Unknown Source:57)
E/JavaBinder( 7405):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzat.zzg(Unknown Source:10)
E/JavaBinder( 7405):    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.zza(Unknown Source:62)
E/JavaBinder( 7405):    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth$zzb.zza(Unknown Source:5)
E/JavaBinder( 7405):    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzcr.zzdx(Unknown Source:15)
E/JavaBinder( 7405):    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzen.zzen(Unknown Source:35)
E/JavaBinder( 7405):    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzen.zza(Unknown Source:41)
E/JavaBinder( 7405):    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzep.zza(Unknown Source:9)
E/JavaBinder( 7405):    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzdx.dispatchTransaction(Unknown Source:9)
E/JavaBinder( 7405):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_auth.zza.onTransact(Unknown Source:13)
E/JavaBinder( 7405):    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:752)
E/JavaBinder( 7405): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.util.ArrayMap" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.musiplangroup.musiplan-hT4gof_IgKcfYAPoywPYJw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.musiplangroup.musiplan-hT4gof_IgKcfYAPoywPYJw==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.musiplangroup.musiplan-hT4gof_IgKcfYAPoywPYJw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64]]
E/JavaBinder( 7405):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:169)
E/JavaBinder( 7405):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
E/JavaBinder( 7405):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
E/JavaBinder( 7405):    ... 16 more
E/AndroidRuntime( 7405): FATAL EXCEPTION: Binder:7405_1
E/AndroidRuntime( 7405): Process: com.musiplangroup.musiplan, PID: 7405
E/AndroidRuntime( 7405): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/util/ArrayMap;
E/AndroidRuntime( 7405):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzam.zzc(Unknown Source:22)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7405):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzam.zzde(Unknown Source:17)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7405):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzam.zzdd(Unknown Source:8)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7405):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzan.zzdf(Unknown Source:1)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7405):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzm.isAnonymous(Unknown Source:47)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7405):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzat.zzi(Unknown Source:57)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7405):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzat.zzg(Unknown Source:10)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7405):    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.zza(Unknown Source:62)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7405):    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth$zzb.zza(Unknown Source:5)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7405):    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzcr.zzdx(Unknown Source:15)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7405):    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzen.zzen(Unknown Source:35)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7405):    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzen.zza(Unknown Source:41)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7405):    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzep.zza(Unknown Source:9)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7405):    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzdx.dispatchTransaction(Unknown Source:9)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7405):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_auth.zza.onTransact(Unknown Source:13)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7405):    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:752)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7405): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.util.ArrayMap" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.musiplangroup.musiplan-hT4gof_IgKcfYAPoywPYJw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.musiplangroup.musiplan-hT4gof_IgKcfYAPoywPYJw==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.musiplangroup.musiplan-hT4gof_IgKcfYAPoywPYJw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64]]
E/AndroidRuntime( 7405):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:169)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7405):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7405):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7405):    ... 16 more
W/OPDiagnose( 7405): getService:OPDiagnoseService NULL
D/OSTracker( 7405): OS Event: crash
D/AbstractTracker( 7405): Event success
I/Process ( 7405): Sending signal. PID: 7405 SIG: 9
```

As said before, the code above works fine for catching errors like `wrong password` or `wrong email`, and returns the code created in the switch statement. However, on a successful login it causes a crash with that error message.

I'm using the `firebase_auth` package for this.

I would really appreciate some help on this.

Comment: Hi danwillm did you ever find the solution for this? I'm in the exact same situation

Comment: hi @Nemesisjust seen your comment - it had to do with android x

Comment: @Nemesis I just followed google's guide for upgrading and all was well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the v4 support library in your app. Try adding v4 support library as a gradle dependency

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.support/support-v4
compile group: 'com.android.support', name: 'support-v4', version: '28.0.0'
```

Comment: Where can I add this line?

Comment: in your build.gradle (but look at the version - all Versions of com.android.support must match)

Comment: Where can I add this in the file?

Comment: Where abouts do I add this? in `dependenices?`

Answer (score 0):

What he means is, add it to the dependency section of your app level Gradle file like this

`compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'`

Answer (score 0):

I ran in the same problem, try to migrate your project to androidx https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility

Answer (score 0):

It has to do somehow with incompatibilities with AndroidX.

I downgraded all my firebase references to versions that don't deal with AndroidX in my pubspec.yaml

```
firebase_core: ^0.2.5+1
firebase_auth: ^0.7.0
```

If you are using any other firebase libraries, like `cloud_firestore`, you will likely need to downgrade those too since they depend on the `firebase_core` module.

After that change, everything works again. Most of these libraries are in version 0.X anyway so I assume they will fix this kind of issues in future versions.

Answer (score 0):

Removing:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.1'
```

from my **app/build.gradle** fixed this issue.

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup
"You no longer need to add the Android library com.google.firebase:firebase-core.

In June 2019, all the Firebase SDKs for Android migrated from the Android Support Libraries to the Jetpack (AndroidX) Libraries."